# Is MacOS (OSX) a multi-user-operating-system?

Tags: osx, vnc, multiuser

We had to set up a MacOS (OSX) for testing iPhone app-development, but it was really awful to realize that mouse speed and input language, or applications that run as services (teamviewer) can be changed by any user that uses the system. We connect to the system by VNC, but one of our collegues is next to the device and uses wired connection, and he gets strange effects like seeing an user working on his desktop and so on. This only happens if the VNC-user logs in before a non-VNC-user ever logged in to the system. Is MacOS (OSX) a multi-user operating-system?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/osx/server/

Comment: hm ... a OSX server ... i will analyze that link, thx

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/8966/mac-os-x-multi-user-thin-client-server-terminal-server

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thx that's a good ressource, that was the stuff i'm searching

Comment: the user that is connected without VNC sees on his display one of the remote users working, but can not log in, because the log in screen is gone, so this situation can only happen if a remote user connects before the local user has logged in

Comment: found a duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time

Answer (score 4):

OS X in itself is a multi-tasking, multi-user OS, **but VNC is *desktop control software***, so software that *controls 1 desktop* (unless set up in such a way that multiple *virtual* desktops can be controlled remotely).

**So what you're seeing is standard behaviour of the *software* you're using, not of the underlying OS...**

#### ;-)

Comment: hehe nice answer Fabby, but OSX provides a VNC-version to remotely access the computer for mutliple user accounts, we are using tightVNC on Windows to access the Macintosh

Comment: the user that is connected without VNC sees on his display one of the remote users working, but can not log in, because the log in screen is gone, so this situation can only happen if a remote user connects before the local user has logged in

Comment: Ah, want me to delete the answer so your question will attract better answers?  Also, please put these comments into your question so that not someone else comes up with the same answer after I delete it...  **;-)  :P**

Comment: let it stay :) is nice

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not specify if you are using OS X Server or not, let me presume not and suggest that you might be violating the EULA:

> 2H. Remote Desktop Connections. Subject to the terms and conditions of
>   this License, when remotely connecting from another computer or
>   electronic device (each a “Device”) to an Apple- branded computer that
>   is running the Apple Software (for purposes of this Section, such
>   Apple- branded computer is referred to as the “Home Mac”), whether
>   through the Screen Sharing feature or through any other means:
>
> (i) only one (1) Device may remotely connect at any one time, whether
>   directly or indirectly, to control the graphical desktop session of
>   the Apple Software that is running and being displayed on the Home
>   Mac; and
>
> (ii) a reasonable number of Devices may remotely connect at the same
>   time for the sole purpose of simultaneously observing the same
>   graphical desktop session of the Apple Software that is running and
>   being displayed on the Home Mac, as long as they do not control the
>   Apple Software in any way; but
>
> (iii) only one (1) Apple-branded Device may remotely connect at any
>   one time, whether directly or indirectly, to control a separate
>   graphical desktop session of the Apple Software that is different from
>   the one running and being displayed on the Home Mac, and such
>   connection may only be made through the Screen Sharing feature of the
>   Apple Software.
>
> Except as expressly permitted in this Section 2H, or except as
>   otherwise licensed by Apple, you agree not to use the Apple Software,
>   or any of its functionality, in connection with service bureau,
>   time-sharing, terminal sharing or other similar types of services,
>   whether such services are being provided within your own organization
>   or to third parties.

From [here](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1011.pdf) .

So that boils down to the fact that *legally* you can connect multiple devices to **view** the same session, but only connect **one other Apple device** to control a separate session.

After a *very *quick glance I don't see the same restrictions under [OS X Server](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSXServer5.pdf).

Comment: Ok, so in a nutshell... OS X Server is single-user, single-seat system by license. Sort of like buying a gun would require you to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: does everyone agree? should ***this*** be the ***"solution"***?

Comment: @orion no, a quick search suggests that **OS X Server** may be permitted to serve multiple desktops. But OS X *Client* is only permitted to serve one extra desktop to another *Apple* device.

Comment: @Fabby in that case the answer is “yes it is”, many users can log in via SSH and use the system via a shell. Given the history around licensing in the UNIX and Linux world, licence talk is more than valid, I'd have thought.

Comment: comment removed.

Comment: well I am not happy with the answer at all, everyone knows that Apple advertises its operating system to be multi-user-capable, based on German laws, it is forbidden to advertise a system as multi-user-operating system and then deny mutliple users the access, Apple's EULA is *illegal* in german-speaking countries

Comment: Personally I don't think I've seen Apple promote multiple users using OS X concurrently? And then there is the definition, is two concurrent Desktop users not “multiple”? Is many users logged in via something like SSH not “multiple”? Like I say, OS X Server doesn't appear to have these limitations, but I haven't read it in full. You would do well to become familiar with potential technical and legal restrictions before you deploy solutions in the future.

Comment: Am I the only one to find out that every time we have contact to Apple products, there is no technical, but legal issues to be the problems.

Comment: here is an instructions-guide from Apple with information how to set up mulitple users: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18891?locale=de_AT&viewlocale=de_DE

Comment: have a look at this, Apple says it, you can use the Mac from remote without interrupting another user working on that device: https://web.archive.org/web/20110612085914/http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html

Comment: here is an article that advertises the Mac OS multi user exerpience, maybe it is paid advertisement: http://9to5mac.com/2011/02/27/10-7-lion-allows-multi-user-remote-computing/

Comment: Neither of those links states how many, and both could be read that only one user can log in remotely while another is using it locally. Neither link gives me the impression that OS X has "proper" terminal-server like capabilities. The instruction guide you linked to is just for user accounts, not for concurrent access…Multiple account != concurrent use!

Comment: multiple users != multiple accounts, the article from archive.org states explicitely, "you can work, while another one works on the system", that means it is concurrent

Comment: *shrug* what you want to do I don't think you can do, certainly not with OS X Client. Part of that is due to licensing restrictions. */me out*